# Is it possible to execute a query against a sqlite database with a single line terminal command?

Tags: android, sqlite, terminal

I want to perform an insert in a sqlite database, programatically from my app. I don't want to create a Database adapter, or any of that... Instead, since it's a simple statement, I thought about running a shell command.

Normally, I would do like:

```
# sqlite3 database.db
```

And then:

```
sqlite3> INSERT INTO table VALUES (something);
```

But, I would like to know if **it is possible to run a query against a sqlite database in a single command?**

If so, I could use the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec('command')` method from within my app.

Comment: This will be slower, more CPU intensive, more system RAM intensive, and more problematic to debug (e.g., no exceptions) than is `db=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...); db.execSQL(...); db.close()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. Just put the SQL as an argument on the command line:

```
sqlite3 database.db "INSERT INTO table VALUES (something)"
```

Note that not all Android devices ship with a sqlite3 executable. Consider doing the database operations in your code instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is for a private project, and I also wanted to call this command using adb... So this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to exec multiple statements, and you are on bash (or any other POSIX shell):

```sh
sqlite3 data.db3 << EOF
SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;
EOF
```